# suppose that $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a nonempty bounded set, and that $\sup E\notin E$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $\sup E$ such that $x_n\in E$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

My attempt at a solution:

By the Approximation Property, $\exists x_1\in E$ such that, for any $\epsilon>0$ 
$$\sup E-\epsilon<x_1\leq\sup E$$
Since $\sup E\notin E$, $x$ is strictly less than $\sup E$. Applying the approximation property again, we get $$\sup E-\epsilon<x_1<x_2<\sup E$$ Keep applying the approximation property so that 
$$\sup E-\epsilon<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n<\sup E$$
This gives you $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
\Subtracting $\sup E$ from every term gives 
$$-\epsilon<x_n-\sup E<0\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}$$ Multiplying both sides by -1 gives $$\epsilon>\sup -x_n>0\Leftrightarrow \epsilon>\vert x_n-\sup E\vert,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ so $x_n\to\sup E$ as $n\to\infty$.

However, this is wrong, and I am not entirely sure why. I am fairly certain that the correct proof involves the Approximation Property, but other than that I am lost.

Comment: Use your original approximation property infinitely many times, taking $\epsilon=1/n$.

Comment: The hint corrects your method.  The reason that your argument doesn't work is a bit technical.  You choose a particular value of $\epsilon$ and you succeed in finding a sequence.  But your sequence depends on $\epsilon$.  If you change $\epsilon$ you are changing your sequence.  It "looks like" you have something that holds for all $\epsilon$ but not so.

Comment: As the previous comments say,all you get is that $\sup \{x_n : n\in N\}$ does not exceed the number called "sup $E$"...... Instead take  $\epsilon_n$ for each $x_n$ with $\epsilon_n$ converging to $0$. For example $ (\sup E)-1/n<x_n<\sup E$ with $1/n=\epsilon_n$.